# Bluetooth on macOS is much much slower than iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth

I am working on Bluetooth LE using CoreBluetooth on macOS. The app (master) will listen to a characteristic notification from Bluetooth device (slave). And I see that, the macOS only receives 2 packets per second, while the same processing code running on iOS receives about 30 packets per second! I did use other tools for logging and get the same result.

– On iOS, I use the [LightBlue Explorer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth-low-energy/id557428110?mt=8):

[image]

– On macOS, I use the Hardware IO tools for Xcode:
[image]

My testing devices are:

- iOS: iPad Air running iOS 10.2.1
- macOS: Macbook pro 2015 running
  macOS 10.12.3

So, the bluetooth on macOS is much much slower than iOS, is that true?

Thank you,

Minh

**Edited on April 7, 2017:**

I think I know where the problem comes from. I tried with Apple Magic Mouse 2 and the bluetooth throughput is about 2KB/s. Then, I configured my slave device with HID services. Now, my MBP can pair with the device and the bluetooth throughput is high. So I think that the unpaired bluetooth signal was filtered by the macOS. Please check this [link](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH10549?locale=en_US) for the supported profiles.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am experiencing similar issue on MBP 2016 running 10.12.5 Beta.

Comment: Hi @Reggian,

Please see my edit above.